# web view don't load when language change but in chrome it does reload

Tags: android, webview

i am making a web view app where there is a  language tabs on header like spinner when i change language in chrome it do refresh  and language changes but in web view it don't detect language change on same link and don't restart until manually restart i have enabled java script and sharing some code i search every where but didn't get any solution. and the languages load at same time when page load.

```
 mWebView = (AdvancedWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,URL,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setCookiesEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setDesktopMode(true);
    mWebView.setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setClickable(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

Comment: probably because `Chrome` is not a WebVIew, and those changings are implemented there same way as you have to implement in your app. Now it is not clear how exactly you change the language.

Comment: language change from the link https://www.thespineapp.com/#/ just go to this link an try it

Comment: language change on same url

Comment: the web site is using cookies to change language from what I can see. I see you have enabled the, so I don't know why it doesn't work. Any way, don't expect WebView to work as a full Web Browser, it's functions are always limited. Probably `Chrome custom tabs` will work for you

Comment: can i have any link of the example that i use

Comment: always google first